# "cannot open display" with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, display, xorg

I am controlling my PI through my PC (wich is running Windows 7) using Putty to type in commands and tightvnc viewer to access the GUI.

I can launch programs with the TightVNC viewer GUI or TightVNC viewer LXterminal. However if I try to launch them on the command line with the putty shell I get an error.

Eg. if I type: `midori`
I will get:
`Midori - cannot open display`

I have read up about X, etc... but can't figure out what to do.

(When I type: `echo $DISPLAY`, I get a blank line, in case this is any help).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access an UNIX server from a Windows client, my preferred combination is **[PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) + [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)**. Xming is **easy to install**, **lightweight**, **fast**, **stable**, and works pretty well overall.

The procedure ([also explained here](http://solaris.reys.net/how-to-x11-forwarding-using-ssh-putty-and-xming/)):

- **Enable the X11 forwarding option** in PuTTY (Configuration > Connection > SSH > X11 > Enable X11 forwarding)
- **Start Xming** on your Windows machine: `...\Xming\Xming.exe :0 -clipboard -multiwindow`
- **Connect** to your Raspberry PI with PuTTY
- **Launch** any X application from your PuTTY ssh console

The application should appear on it's own window (if you set the `-multiwindow` Xming command-line option), and seamlessly integrate onto the host.

The nice thing is that it's rather lightweight, you do not need to run a full-blown X desktop on the Raspberry. With a decent network connection between the client and the host you do not feel any lag. And remember that *client* and *host* are swapped from their usual understanding according to X11 conventions!

*Note 1*: I don't know anything about TightVNC, but simply activating X11 forwarding in PuTTY should be enough to make that work with any X server on your Windows machine. But again, Xming rocks!

*Note 2*: There is even a documentation on using PuTTY on [Xming website](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php).

Comment: +1 for mentioning Xming. Looks really good. I have been using Cygwin X for same purpose. Will give Xming a try.

Comment: Thanks. If you only need a X server, indeed Xming is *really* better. Cygwin is a full blown Unix compatibility layer for Windows, and you end up using a small percentage of the system, even if you install the bare minimum for X.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH's X11 forwarding capabilities.

X11 forwarding needs to be enabled on both the client side and the server side.

On the server side, `X11Forwarding yes` must specified in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Note that the default is no forwarding (some distributions turn it on in their default /etc/ssh/sshd_config), and that the user cannot override this setting.

On the client side, the -X (capital X) option to ssh enables X11 forwarding, and you can make this the default (for all connections or for a specific conection) with `ForwardX11 yes` in ~/.ssh/config.

Then try to connect from client to server with -X or -Y option.

ssh -Y user@rpi-server

And run your command: `midori`

Source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine

Comment: thanks for the reply . though I should have said that I am on MS Windows.

Comment: There is an option in Putty (windows SSH/Telnet application) to use X11 forwarding. Check it : http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the X applications to run **and** display on the Pi (which is the usual way to do things). In that case you don't want to do any X-Forwarding or run an additional X client. You just have to let the ssh session know you intend to use the Pi's display.

After ssh'ing in to the pi (eg. using Putty), run:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

From then on, any GUI application you execute will use the Pi's display and you'll be able to see it in your VNC session.

I used [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/68581/76504) for reference.