# Cannot open display through SSH

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh

I'm using Cygwin to control my RPi over ssh,

```
ssh pi@192.168.0.18
```

however if I try to launch an application (using Geany as an example):

```
sudo geany
```

I get the response: **Geany: Cannot open display**. I'm not sure what's going on here, so I'd be very grateful to receive any tips!

***More (hopefully useful) information***

- If I run the command on the Pi, everything works as expected.
- If I launch Xwin server and run: `export DISPLAY=:0.0` `ssh -Y pi@192.168.0.1` `sudo geany` the window is forwarded to my laptop just as expected.
- Running a java executable over ssh (JavaFX application built with maven) also works as expected (the application is displayed).

Just to be sure - I would like the application window to **open on the Pi**, not the laptop I'm using to ssh into it.

***Edit***

Not all applications return the same error - for example BlueJ throws a Java exception:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

Scratch returns:

```
squeak: could not find any display driver
```

Chromium-browser:

```
[2260:2260:0616/200257.886341:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(495)] Failed to put Xlib into threaded mode. 

2260:2260:0616/200257.899631:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(272)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Does it work without `sudo`? Do not `export DISPLAY`. It should be set automatically if you set it up correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `export DISPLAY=:0.0` AFTER you've established an SSH connection with the RPi

Comment: @Jakuje I have the same behaviour without sudo.

Comment: @Veroxi Ah that did it! Fantastic thank-you so much. What's the correct way to close this thread?

Comment: I'd keep the question up so others can see this if they have the same issue, and put **[SOLVED]** in the title of the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be solved by running `export DISPLAY=:0.0` **after** you've established an SSH connection with the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. Everytime I try it returns `Cannot open display: 0.0`. I tried with 0.0 and 0 through 3, none works. Is there any other value I can try ?

Comment: Note: Don't forget to configure (via `raspi-config`) to set the desktop mode to auto-logon.  Otherwise this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I do that all the time with cygwinx. I do ssh -Y pi@192.168.1.60 I edit files on the pi by opening a gvim window, for example.